# Generate a particular sequence in oracle or c# asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oracle12c

I am using oracle 12c database to store data,and .net asp c# to create a web application.
i am new with oracle and know about the new feature of identity columns.

I want to generate a number xx-y-zzz such that xx is the current financial year,y is a integer belongs to (1-9) and zzz is a value that starts with 001 and is incremented whenever a button is clicked.

and also

->zzz is a number that depends on y,
    eg. 14-1-001 and 14-2-001 can both exist simultaneously
->if the current financial year changes then the value zzz will start from 001

thanks

Comment: I don't think any feature available to generate such pattern, you need to code in C# only to generate such number

Comment: You cannot do it using Identity column. You could write your own `function` in `PL/SQL`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This sort of "smart identifier" is generally not a very smart idea.  The very first step in normalization is to break apart this sort of composite value into its constituent parts.  The current financial  year clearly belongs in a separate column.  I'm not sure what y represents but that probably belongs in a separate column.  If you really need the composite identifier, it generally makes more sense to build it in the query/ in a view.